# What mediawiki is need hook to write plugin which will add html just inside <body>

Tags: php, mediawiki

This question is addressed **only to people having some experience in programming MediaWiki plugins**.

I want to put some **header at top of page with use plugin and html**. I need to put **some html code as the first tag after `<body>` opens** to not but not know which hook or method should I use to achieve goal - Mediawiki has too much hooks to choose please suggest one.

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks

Result after plugin run should look like this:

```
<< Custom header>>
-----
<< Unchanged Mediawiki page >>
```

Could you help with this trivial problem?

One possible solution is to inject some JavaScript to create HTML but it is artificial and it will not work with Google Search Bot.

I think that many people want to put something on the top of their MediaWiki-s but without writing and maintain yet another skin or branching Mediawiki and it is supported today.

Comment: You really want to insert something after `</body>`?

Comment: @Bergi Not want insert after </body> but after <body> - see illustration "should look like" - after </body> is "too late".

Comment: Why not just edit the `MediaWiki:Sitenotice` page? It'll allow you to insert a site-wide branding, nav, or other special features.

Comment: I think you should consider to give more details and explain the situation you are in.  Most of the commentators, me included, suppose that you're looking in wrong direction.  I remember your previous question — you wanted to put some generated and very customized stuff near page header — and I still have some feeling that there is better way to get what you want, you're just asking wrong questions.

Comment: "I think that many people want to put something on the top of their MediaWiki-s but without writing and maintain yet another skin or branching Mediawiki and it is supported today." — this is what `MediaWiki:Sitenotice` page is used primarily for.  But yes, if your needs are more custom, you're welcome to give your solution back to free software.

Answer (score 0):

But if you think hooks is what you want, I'd go with [ParserBeforeTidy](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/ParserBeforeTidy).  The hooks list is long but divided into sections, and "Page Rendering" is section you want to check.  Parser(Before/After)Tidy are called on fully generated page, so they offer the highest degree of customization (which may be undesired, though).

Comment: I try this solution - looks good to test it. I try many hooks but never experiment with this thanks for suggestions. I will give some points if it works.